# How can i solve a touch event bug in my mobile game

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, touch-event

**I'm building a match 3 game for mobile with ionic/angular.
For that i studied how touch gestures work.**

I have a problem i'm trying to solve since a few days ago without success.

If i swipe move a tile to the left or to the right i can only move it across one tile.

If i move one tile up or down i can move it over as many tiles as i want.

I need to be able to move a tile left or right across as many tiles as i want.

Each tile has a with of 50px, therefore the sensitivity is equal to 50.

One strange thing i noticed and i'm not able to solve is that the onTouchEnd only fires if i swipe up or down. That maybe one of the causes of the problem because this.selectedTile = null does not happens and the touchmove does not have a new reference to swipe across path with more than 2 tiles.

I attached the relevant code and a picture of the game board.

**Can somebody help me?**

LOGIC (creating game board, touch gestures):

```
generateGameBoard(): void {
        this.startTimer();
        const rows = 6;
        const cols = 6;
        const board: Cell[][] = [];

    // Calculate the total number of tiles needed for pairs of 3
    const totalPairsOf3 = Math.floor((rows * cols) / 3);
    let generatedPairsOf3 = 0;

    // Shuffle the Egyptian hieroglyphs array to ensure randomness
    const shuffledHieroglyphs = this.shuffleArray(this.symbols);

    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      const row: Cell[] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        // Check if we have generated enough pairs of 3
        if (generatedPairsOf3 < totalPairsOf3) {
          // Generate pairs of 3
          const pairIndex = generatedPairsOf3 % shuffledHieroglyphs.length;
          const pairHieroglyph = shuffledHieroglyphs[pairIndex];
          row.push({
            symbol: pairHieroglyph?.symbol,
            color: pairHieroglyph?.color,
          });
          generatedPairsOf3++;
        } else {
          // Fill the remaining tiles with random tiles
          const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.symbols.length);
          const randomHieroglyph = this.symbols[randomIndex];
          row.push({
            symbol: randomHieroglyph?.symbol,
            color: randomHieroglyph?.color,
          });
        }
      }
      board.push(row);
    }

    this.gameBoard = board;
    this.checkAdjacentTiles();
  }


shuffleArray(array: any[]): any[] {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
  }

onTouchStart(event: TouchEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const touchedElement = event.touches[0].target as HTMLElement;
    if (!touchedElement || !touchedElement.dataset) return;

    const touchedRow = parseInt(touchedElement.dataset['row'] || '0', 10);
    const touchedCol = parseInt(touchedElement.dataset['col'] || '0', 10);

    console.log('Touched row:', touchedRow, 'Touched col:', touchedCol);

    this.selectedTile = { row: touchedRow, col: touchedCol };
    this.startX = event.touches[0].clientX;
    this.startY = event.touches[0].clientY;
  }


onTouchMove(event: TouchEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!this.selectedTile) return;

    const currentX = event.touches[0].clientX;
    const currentY = event.touches[0].clientY;

    const deltaX = currentX - this.startX;
    const deltaY = currentY - this.startY;

    const sensitivity = 50;

    // Check if movement is primarily horizontal or vertical

    const absDeltaX = Math.abs(deltaX);
    const absDeltaY = Math.abs(deltaY);

    const numTilesToMoveX = Math.floor(absDeltaX / 50);
    const numTilesToMoveY = Math.floor(absDeltaY / 50);

    let newRow = this.selectedTile.row;
    let newCol = this.selectedTile.col;

    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
      // Horizontal movement
      if (deltaX > sensitivity) {
        // Swipe right
        console.log('Swiped right');
        newRow += numTilesToMoveX;
      } else if (deltaX < -sensitivity) {
        // Swipe left
        console.log('Swiped left');
        newRow -= numTilesToMoveX;
      }
    } else {
      // Vertical movement
      if (deltaY > sensitivity) {
        // Swipe down
        console.log('Swiped down');
        newCol += numTilesToMoveY;
      } else if (deltaY < -sensitivity) {
        // Swipe up
        console.log('Swiped up');
        newCol -= numTilesToMoveY;
      }
    }

    newRow = Math.max(0, Math.min(newRow, this.gameBoard[0].length - 1));
    newCol = Math.max(0, Math.min(newCol, this.gameBoard[0].length - 1));

    if (newRow !== this.selectedTile.row || newCol !== this.selectedTile.col) {
      // Swap the tiles
      [
        this.gameBoard[newRow][newCol],
        this.gameBoard[this.selectedTile.row][this.selectedTile.col],
      ] = [
        this.gameBoard[this.selectedTile.row][this.selectedTile.col],
        this.gameBoard[newRow][newCol],
      ];

      // Update the selected tile's position
      this.selectedTile.row = newRow;
      this.selectedTile.col = newCol;

      // Update the start position for the next calculation
      this.startX = currentX;
      this.startY = currentY;
    }
  }

  onTouchCancel(event: TouchEvent) {
    this.onTouchEnd(event);
  }

  onTouchEnd(event: TouchEvent) {
    console.log('touchend');
    this.soundService.playSfx();
    this.checkAdjacentTiles();
    event.preventDefault();
    this.selectedTile = null;
  }
```

MARKUP:

```
  <div
    class="game-board"
    (touchstart)="onTouchStart($event)"
    (touchmove)="onTouchMove($event)"
    (touchcancel)="onTouchCancel($event)"
    (touchend)="onTouchEnd($event)"
  >
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of gameBoard; let i = index">
      <div
        class="cell"
        *ngFor="let cell of row; let j = index"
        [attr.data-row]="i"
        [attr.data-col]="j"
        [style.color]="cell.color"
        [class.glow]="cell.glow"
      >
        {{ cell.symbol }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: From your description, the problem could come from complex logic, rather than a specific technology.

What if you would use the divide and conquer method and split the domain model up into smaller, more or less independent models with clear responsibility? For example, introduce specific classes for GameBoard, and for Tile (each tile could have a state, selected or not), make a function/class with the responsibility to check tile matches, etc. This would enable you to isolate your problem, and make it much easier to debug your code.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand what you want to achieve, but touch move isn't supported also on all devices (`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events`).. so even if touch events worked for android it will not work for ios.. So i think it's better to use gestures and apply what you want as it will applicable for both android and ios using gestures (`https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/gestures`)

Comment: I will take a look at the ionic gestures to see if they are up to solve the problem.
Tanks Mostafa.